# BVPs for elliptic PDOs: When do Green functions ($L^2$ inverses) define pseudo-differential operators in the interior?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations, singular-integrals, pseudo-differential-operators

Let me illustrate my question by starting with the simplest possible example: Let us consider $P := - \mathrm{d}^2/\mathrm{d}x^2$, an elliptic partial differential operator on $\mathbb{R}$; let us also consider the following boundary-value problem on the interval $\overline{\Omega} = [0,1]$:
\begin{equation}
P u = f, \qquad u(0)=u(1)=0.
\end{equation}
As is (I think) well-known, when seen as an operator $L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$, $P$ is unbounded.  However, it is closed on the dense domain $D(P)  := H^2(\Omega) \cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ where $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_{\mathrm{c}}^\infty(\Omega)$ in the $H^1$ norm (so that any element of this space has vanishing trace on $\partial \Omega = \{0,1\}$, i.e. it satisfies the Dirichlet boundary condition above in a weak sense).  Furthermore, $0$ is in the resolvent of $(P,D(P))$, i.e. there exists a bounded inverse $P^{-1} : L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$.  In fact, in this example the inverse is easily computed: it is the integral operator defined by the (continuous, as it happens) kernel
\begin{equation}
G(x,y) = \begin{cases} x(1-y) & x \leq y \\ y(1-x) &x > y \end{cases}, \quad (x,y) \in \Omega \times \Omega.
\end{equation}
Of course, when viewed as a distribution in $\mathscr{D}'(\Omega \times \Omega)$, $G$ is the Schwartz kernel of $P^{-1}$ which we know on abstract grounds must exist since $P^{-1} : C_{\mathrm{c}}^{\infty}(\Omega) \to \mathscr{D}'(\Omega)$ is continuous.

My question is the following: in this example and in more general examples where $P$ is a second-order elliptic differential operator on, say, an open (and not necessarily compact) region $\Omega$ with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and assuming that we can find a suitable dense domain $D(P)$ for $P$ as above so that $(P,D(P))$ has a bounded inverse $P^{-1} : L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$, **does the Schwartz kernel $G$ of $P^{-1}$ define a pseudodifferential operator on $\Omega$?**

Comment: The question is _just_ too old to migrate. On Monday it would have been possible I think (maybe Sunday, I don't know if it's $< 60$ or $\leqslant 60$ days). You could just re-post it on MO.

Comment: This has now been answered in the positive in a [MO repost](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285548/bvps-for-elliptic-pdos-when-do-green-functions-l2-inverses-define-pseudo-d/287324#287324).

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert on the topic, but it seems to me that you are looking for Boutet de Monvel's calculus. In this calculus you can construct parametrices of pseudodifferential operators with boundary conditions.
So, in short the answer is yes and the remnant you get is a so-called singular Greens operator which is smoothing in the interior, but acts as a psdo on the boundary. A good reference is the book by Grubb (there is also an article by Schrohe (short introduction to ..) which gives an overview of the calculus, but no applications).

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I had found the literature you mention and also felt it was relevant (sorry for forgetting to say this in my question). However, in the end I couldn't extract an answer to my question from there. In particular, I would be grateful if you could add some further hints as to why you think the answer is affirmative.

There is a reference I found which does answer exactly the kind of question I posed above, in a very special case (special geometry, special operators). See Theorem 2.10 in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410186v1.

Comment: The paper treats the case of a non-compact manifold, i assumed $\bar{\Omega}$ to be compact. Well, the point is that the parametrix is in the calculus and its difference to the inverse should be smoothing (i'm not sure about that, but i think it is true).

Comment: I was aware of the fact that if $\Omega$ is a smooth compact manifold *without boundary*, then if an elliptic operator is $L^2$ invertible its inverse is pseudodifferential -- I think the proof goes along the same lines as in your last comment. However I still don't see how to adapt things to what I am interested in. Notice that if we forget about the rest of $\mathbb{R}^n$ altogether in my question, we are simply left with a problem about an elliptic operator on a non-compact Riemannian manifold $\Omega$.